# Facetting with factorised variables and geom_hline / geom_vline

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, geom-hline

Consider this code:

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(x = drat, y = wt)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 3) +
  facet_grid(~ cyl)                       ## works

ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(x = drat, y = wt)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 3) +
  facet_grid(~ factor(cyl))              ## does not work

# Error in factor(cyl) : object 'cyl' not found

# removing geom_hline: works again.
```

[Google](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/QPVT4ZmIFz0) helped me to find a debug, namely wrapping `intercept` into `aes`

```
ggplot(data = mtcars) +
  geom_point(aes(x = drat, y = wt)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 3)) +
  facet_grid(~ factor(cyl))                  # works

# R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)  
# ggplot2_2.2.1
```

[Hadley writes here](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1958) that functions as variables need to be in every layer. (which sounds mysterious to me)

Why does this happen when factorising the facet variable?

Comment: From the link you provided it seems that it's a known limitation. At least there is a workaround for it.

Comment: @MHammer thanks for this consideration - however, it does not answer my question why this happens only when factorising. Do you have an idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's my best guess and explanation.

When Hadley says:

> This is a known limitation of facetting with a function - the variables you use have to be present on every layer.

He means in ggplot, when you're going to use a function in the facetting function, you need to have the variable in every `geom`. The issue occurs because there `cyl` variable is not present in the `hline` `geom`.

It's important to remember, this is a limitation, not ideal behaviour. Moreso, a consequence of how their efficient code works, is that when using functions to facet, the variables must be present in every `geom`.

Without looking into the specifics of the `ggplot2` functions, I'm guessing what wrapping `aes` around the `yintercept` argument does, is give an aesthetic mapping to the `geom_hline` function. The `aes` function maps variables to components of the plot, rather than static values. It's an important distinction. Even though we still set `yintercept = 3`, the fact that we have placed it in the aesthetic mapping, must somehow reference that `cyl` also exists in this space. That is, it connects `geom_hline` indirectly with `cyl`, meaning it's now in the layer, and no longer a limitation.

This may not be an entirely satisfying answer, but without reading over the `ggplot2` code to try and work out specifically why this limitation occurs, this might be as good as you'll get for now. Hopefully one of these workarounds is sufficient for you :)

Comment: oops. finally understood haha. Thanks !!